# I Need to customize month name in android.widget.datepicker

Tags: android, xamarin, datepicker

this is my code . i want to convert calendar to persian calendar and i need to change month names

```
PersianCalendar persianCalendar = new PersianCalendar();
DatePicker calObj = new DatePicker(FrContext);

DateTime minDate = new DateTime(1300, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
minDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(minDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTimeOffset min_Date = minDate;

DateTime maxDate = new DateTime(1500, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
maxDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(maxDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTimeOffset max_Date = maxDate;

calObj.MinDate = min_Date.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
calObj.MaxDate = max_Date.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();

calObj.DateTime = new DateTime(persianCalendar.GetYear(DateTime.Now),
persianCalendar.GetMonth(DateTime.Now),
persianCalendar.GetDayOfMonth(DateTime.Now),
0,0,0,
persianCalendar.GetEra(DateTime.Now));

AlertDialog.Builder aaa = new AlertDialog.Builder(FrContext);
aaa.SetView(calObj);
aaa.Show();
```

i used below code for set culture month names . but not work

```
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var clture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fa-IR");
        clture.DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormatInfo()
        {
            MonthNames = new string[] { "فروردین", "اردیبهشت", "خرداد", "تیر", "مرداد", "شهریور", "مهر", "آبان", "آذر", "دی", "بهمن", "اسفند", "" },
            MonthGenitiveNames = new string[] { "فروردین", "اردیبهشت", "خرداد", "تیر", "مرداد", "شهریور", "مهر", "آبان", "آذر", "دی", "بهمن", "اسفند", "" }
        };
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = clture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = clture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = clture;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Create your fragment here
    }
```

Comment: You should use the [CultureInfo class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Globalization.CultureInfo/) to archive that.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to convert calendar to persian calendar and i need to change month names

Answer from `Xamarin.Forums`: [Another calendar type for datepicker](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/48774/another-calendar-type-for-datepicker).

As MohammadRezaMoradi said, you could download the [PersianMaterialDateTimePicker](https://github.com/mohamad-amin/PersianMaterialDateTimePicker)
and convert to dll with vs.

For example：Add the `PersianMaterialDateTimePicker` [dll](https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/FileUpload/28/28838a4a9101dff436d6ceef6fb5ee.rar) to your project. Then use the persian `Datepicker` like this:

```
 Com.Mohamadamin.Persianmaterialdatetimepicker.Date.DatePickerDialog d = new Com.Mohamadamin.Persianmaterialdatetimepicker.Date.DatePickerDialog();
 d.Show(FragmentManager, "test");
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COnvN.png).

Comment: @JalalOnagh, you display the datepicker in  `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment`?

Comment: @JalalOnagh, you need change the [DatePickerDialog](https://github.com/mohamad-amin/PersianMaterialDateTimePicker/blob/master/persianmaterialdatetimepicker/src/main/java/com/mohamadamin/persianmaterialdatetimepicker/date/DatePickerDialog.java) extends `Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment` instead of `Android.App.DialogFragment`.

Comment: yes . i display the datepicker in Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment